# Can't upload files or attachments

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer

I have tried several times to upload files to my blog and attach files to GMail emails. Each time, the file says "uploading" however the process never completes. Do you have any suggestions on what might be causing this? I have tried this in both Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox. The computer is running XP Pro.

Comment: How long do you wait before giving up on it? What are the exact messages you receive (if any)?

Comment: I have waited in excess of 5 minutes several times. I do not receive any error messages.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're running for AV, anti-malware, firewall, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Uploads fail with BOTH Firefox and IE, on BOTH GMail and your blog?   Almost has to be some kind of software on your PC, most probably some sort of security thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are waiting long enough? Please remember that your upload speed is probably a fraction of your download speed.

I suggest creating a small text file on your machine, making a new email to yourself and trying to attach that text file. If it fails after a few minutes, there is clearly a problem (first thing I would advise is disabling ALL addons, no matter how handy / nice they sound). If it does work, you just need to wait longer.

Comment: I am trying this on a Comcast 12MB/s connection with a 1 MB/s+ upload speed. I have waited > 5 minutes for a 3MB photo. I also tried with a variety of smaller .doc and .txt documents. Same results.